Right click open new powershell file open in PSIDE
I'm still running windows 10 and I'm currently still running psh 5.6 due to company policy. I have local admin on my  machine so I can write to the registry. I'm trying to figure out the quickest way from explorer to do a right click create new powershell script and open it in PSIDE automatically. I've seen it done before I just can't find the steps or a .reg file to add it.
I tried adding this just to get open a new .ps1 file
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ps1\ShellNew]
"NullFile"=""

Nothing happened.
Any help appreciated.
Matt

You could try these 2 methods, but it's really not a scripting problem it's a Windows problem. I still use Windows 10 as well so don't worry you're still in the majority on OS version.
superuser.com
techreplublic
